# How can I create a global state that can be accessed or modified from these pages? I'm using React RouterProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How can I create a global state that can be accessed or modified from these pages?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.css'

import Home from './pages/Home.jsx'
import Login from './pages/Login.jsx'
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp.jsx'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {path: '/', element: <Home />},
  {path: '/login', element: <Login />},
  {path: '/register', element: <SignUp />},
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Comment: React-Router and the `RouterProvider` component haven't anything at all to do with any state management or global state, etc, just use whatever you would use normally. Please [edit] your post to explain in better detail what any actual issue or problem is that you need specific help with. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use **React Context API** to achive this

Create and export your context using `createContext` function from `react`, create your state using `useState` hook from `react`, Then Wrap your `RouterProvider` with the created context `Provider` and pass your state as the context value, you can also pass it within an object if you want to pass more than one state.

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
  { path: "/login", element: <Login /> },
  { path: "/register", element: <Signup /> },
]);

export function App() {
  const myState = useState("Hello from my context.");

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={myState}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And in the below code we simply import the context we just created + `useContext` from `react` and use the provided `myState` value in our component. I tried it with `Home` component. You can try it with any child component of your choice.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { MyContext } from "../app";

function Home() {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(MyContext);

  // Use your setState function as you wish

  return <div>Home: {state}</div>;
}

export default Home;
```